# Anyonic Braiding and Conformal Field Theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, quantum-computer, anyons

I am looking for resources (both pedagogical and newer research articles) on the connection between [topological quantum computation and conformal field theory](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=conformal+field+theory+topological+quantum+computation). In particular, a CFT description of anyonic braiding, fractional statistics, and/or the braid group of which assumes basic knowledge of conformal field theory and topological quantum computation. Does anyone know any good resources on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Moore and Seiberg's "Lectures on RCFT" which is clear and beautiful. From their lectures, you can also get a sense of how the idea of modular tensor category goes into the subject.

In terms of a research article, I would recommend their paper "Classical and quantum conformal field theory".

Unfortunately, both references are sort of old since the developments are made in the 1980s.

Comment: **Before answering, please see [our policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698) on resource recommendation questions.** Please write substantial answers that detail the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, paper or other resource. Explain the nature of the resource so that readers can decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the opinions of others. **Answers containing only a reference to a book or paper will be removed!**

Answer (score 0):

A more modern paper on this subject that was written in the context of topological quantum computation would be the review article [Non-Abelian Anyons and Topological Quantum Computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1889). It includes a review of conformal field theories in the appendix, a very gentle introduction to topological field theories in the beginning, and then dives into plenty of detail (at varying levels of gentleness).